# How to do link prediction with node embeddings?

Tags: machine-learning, graph, recommendation-engine, word-embedding

I am working on an item embedding task in recommendation system and I want to evaluate the performance of the new embedding algorithm with the old ones. I have read some papers about graph embedding and almost every paper mentioned a normal method to evaluate the embeddings which is link prediction. But none of these papers described exactly how you do it. So my question is how to evaluate the embeddings using link prediction?

The algorithm I am trying to apply is:

- First a directed graph is built on user click sequences, each node in the graph represents an item, and if a user once clicked item A then clicked B, there should be two nodes A and B and an edge A-B with weight of 1. When another user clicked A then clicked B, the weight of edge A-B is added by 1.
- Then a new sequence dataset is generated by random walking the graph, using the outbound weights as the teleport probabilities.
- Finally SkipGram is performed on the new sequences to generate the node embeddings.

As many papers mentioned, I removed a certain proportion of the edges in the graph as the positive samples of test set(e.g. 0.25) and randomly generated some fake edges as the negative ones. So what's next? Should I simply generate fake edges for the real edges in the training set, concatenate the embeddings of the two nodes on each edge, and build a common classifier such as logistic regression and test it on the test set? Or should I calculate the AUC on test set with cosine similarity of the two nodes and a label of 0/1 indicating if the two nodes are really connected? Or should I calculate the AUC with the sigmoided dot product of the embeddings of two nodes and a label of 0/1 indicating if the two nodes are really connected, since this is how you compute the probability at last layer?

```py
# these are example describing the three methods above
item_emb = np.random.random(400).reshape(100, 4)  # assume we have 100 items and have embedded them into a 4-dimension vector space.
test_node = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=200).reshape(100, 2)  # assume we have 100 pairs of nodes
test_label = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=100).reshape(100, 1)  # assume this is the label indicating if the pair of nodes are really connected

def test_A():
  # use logistic regression
  train_node = ...  # generate true and fake node pairs in a similar way
  train_label = ... # generate true and fake node pairs in a similar way

  train_feat = np.hstack(
    item_emb[train_node[:, 0]],
    item_emb[train_node[:, 1]])  # concatenate the embeddings
  test_feat = np.hstack(
    item_emb[test_node[:, 0]],
    item_emb[test_node[:, 1]])  # concatenate the embeddings
  lr = sklearn.linear_models.LogisticRegression().fit(train_feat, train_label)
  auc = roc_auc_score(test_label, lr.predict_proba(test_feat)[:,1])
  return auc

def test_B():
  # use cosine similarity
  emb1 = item_emb[test_node[:, 0]]
  emb2 = item_emb[test_node[:, 1]]
  cosine_sim = emb1 * emb2 / (np.linalg.norm(emb1, axis=1)*np.linalg.norm(emb2,axis=1)
  auc = roc_auc_score(test_label, cosine_sim)
  return auc

def test_C():
  # use dot product
  # here we extract the softmax weights and biases from the training network
  softmax_weights = ...  # same shape as item_emb
  softmax_biases = ...  # shape of (item_emb.shape[0], 1)
  embedded_item = item_emb[test_node[:, 0]]  # target item embedding
  softmaxed_context = softmax_weights[test_node[:, 1]] + softmax_biases
  dot_prod = np.sum(embeded_item * softmaxed_context, axis=1)
  auc = roc_auc_score(test_label, dot_prod)
  return auc
```

I have tried the three method in several tests, and they are not always telling the same thing. Some parameter combinations perform better with testA() and bad in other metrics, some the opposite..etc. Sadly there is no such a parameter combination that out performs others in all three metrics...Which metric should I use?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find any solution?
My main question is: when we should extract node embeddings? Before the train/test split or after? If we do that before the split, the embeddings hold the network's topology, so they will bias the link prediction. On the other hand, if we extract embeddings after the split, the same node could have different representations in train and test sets.

Comment: For your question, my advice is that you should always extract the embedding from the training set and test the embedding on the test set, and there is no embedding to extract from the test set. You are right that the embedding extracted before the splitting causes data leakage.

Answer (score 2):

You should investigate some implementations:

1. StellarGraph: [Link prediction with node2vec+Logistic regression](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/demos/link-prediction/node2vec-link-prediction.html)
2. AmpliGraph: [Link prediction with ComplEx](https://docs.ampligraph.org/en/1.3.1/tutorials/AmpliGraphBasicsTutorial.html)

Briefly, one should sample edges (not nodes!) from the original graph, remove them, and learn embeddings on that truncated graph. Then an evaluation is performed on removed edges.

Also, there are two possible cases:

- All possible edges between any pair of nodes are labeled. In this case evaluation metric is ROC AUC, when we learn a classifier to distinguish positives and negatives edges.
- Only positive (real) edges are observed. We don't know if rest pairs are connected or not in the real world. Here we generate negative (fake) nodes for every positive one. The task is considered as *Entity ranking* with next evaluation metrics:

  - [Rank](https://docs.ampligraph.org/en/1.3.1/generated/ampligraph.evaluation.rank_score.html)
  - [Mean Rank (MR)](https://docs.ampligraph.org/en/1.3.1/generated/ampligraph.evaluation.mr_score.html)
  - [Mean Reciprocal Rank (MRR)](https://docs.ampligraph.org/en/1.3.1/generated/ampligraph.evaluation.mrr_score.html)
  - [Hits@N](https://docs.ampligraph.org/en/1.3.1/generated/ampligraph.evaluation.hits_at_n_score.html)

An example can be found in [the paper](https://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-013-5363-6), sections 5.1-5.3.